# How to find node value with longest string length

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Here is my XML:

```
<persons>
   <person>
      <name>Jason</name>
   </person>
   <person>
      <name>John</name>
   </person>
   <person>
      <name>Mary</name>
   </person>
   <person>
      <name>Jennifer</name>
   </person>
</persons>
```

Using XSLT 1.0 I need to find the person with the longest name.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/persons">
    <xsl:for-each select="person">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(name)" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
            <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked great

Comment: Excellent solution! I adapted it to capture the length itself in the variable, to use in a calculation later.